# Can you copy the same Animal Crossing island to two different Switches?

Tags: nintendo-switch, animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have one Switch (Switch-a) that I borrowed and was being used by two kids. I bought two more Switches (Switch-b, Switch-c).

###### Can you copy the same island to two different switches without limitations, yes/no?

If yes, how? And are there any limitations (like keeping one offline)?

From what I have read/researched, all the documentation indicates that you can move (aka "transfer". i.e. copy then delete the source island) and not copy an island. But I thought maybe there would be a way to copy the island to two Switches maybe via "backup/restore" (probably with weird restrictions somehow, like keeping one Switch offline or something).

Anyway I was just curious. In reality what I will very likely do is:

- transfer the island from Switch-a to Switch-b
- on Switch-c the kid will get their own "new" island
- I will transfer their old citizen from Switch-b to Switch-c